# How can i use my self created jQuery function for multiple items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, help me add my function to all divs. I whant to use 'each', but dont know how.

I need 2 alert message, but i become only for first div, when try to use $('div').test() function. With  it still works.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background: yellow;
                float: left;
                margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="a"></div>
        <div id="b"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function( $ ){

                $.fn.test = function() {

                    alert(this.attr('id'));

                };

            })( jQuery );

            //work
            $('#a').test();

            // not work
            //$('div').test();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanx!

Comment: SO is not a help forum, please try and rephrase your questions in a manner that is less specific to you, and more likely to help other users with the same problem.

Comment: @bwheeler96 what is wrong with question? Seems clear to me

Answer (score 3):

Change your alert line to:

```
return this.each(function(){ alert(this.id); });
```

See the docs for jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa95N/).

Comment: But i need to use jquery functions with  'this' same 'this.hide()'

Comment: @iBoozyVoozy You can wrap `this` like `$(this)` and then call jQuery functions on the result like `$(this).hide();` or `$(this).show();`. However, It is highly recommended that you only write `$(this)` once per function scope for efficiency reasons. You can cache the result in a variable called `$this` to avoid doing it more than once.

Comment: So `var $this = $(this);` Then you can do stuff like `$this.show();` and `$this.hide();`

Comment: @iBoozyVoozy Here is an updated JSFiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/h2UWW/ Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/bu952/1/

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.test = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
      alert(this.id);
    });

  };
})( jQuery );


$('div').test();
```

Comment: Sorry, but i need to use jquery functions. example: 'this.hide()'

Comment: @iBoozyVoozy hide what? I really don't understand. What you want to accomplish here? Hide both or a specific one? Instead of `alert(this.id);` use: `$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Your first example...

```
$('#a').test();
```

... works because there is only one element with the id of "a".  However, your second example...

```
$("div").test();
```

... doesn't because it is selecting *all* of the divs on the page.

You will need something like this to support both possibilities:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function() {
        // this is now all selected elements.
        // Loop through each selected element.
        $(this).each(function() {
            // this is now the element being looped.
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ejux/

Answer (score 0):

The answers you got are working for your case. 
If you head for authoring plugins I recommend you read these. Using any of the plugin patterns would prevent you from having problems you posted.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring - it has some tips and a basic structure for a plugin

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/ - allmighty plugin structure

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/ - older version of the above